# JavaFX - how to recognize the position of ScrollBar in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have written this little example application:

[image: screenshot]

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public class Person {

        private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {

            this.firstName.set(firstName);
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            TableView<Person> tv = new TableView<>();
            TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<Person, String>("FirstName");
            col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

            tv.getColumns().add(col);
            tv.setEditable(true);

            col = new TableColumn<Person, String>("LastName");
            col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
            col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            col.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) {

                    System.out.println(tv.getItems().get(1).getLastName());
                }
            });

            tv.getColumns().add(col);

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                tv.getItems().add(new Person("Test" + i, "Test" + i));
            }

            root.getChildren().add(tv);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            tv.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
                // ...
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I want to perform action when the `ScrollBar` has reached the bottom. Then I want to reload more datas from the database. But only then, when the user has seen all the already loaded datas (= scrollbar on the bottom). Do you have nice suggestions to solve this issue?

My first idea was to catch the `MOUSE_RELEASED` event (when the users drags the bar) of the `TableView` and then to check the position of the `ScrollBar`:
- [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#getValue--) gets the position of the bar
- [getMax()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#getMax--) the maximum value (=bottom).

But I can't find a way (without using the css-selector via [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-)) to get the `ScrollBar` from a given `TableView`. So I can't check the position of it in a certain `TableView`.

Do you have any ideas??

I am excited. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this would work: [onScrollToColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#onScrollToColumnProperty)

Comment: Sorry to be off topic (meaning: please, only acknowledge if you wish), are you getting a copying effect in your cells, where editing one cell is resulting in all other cells in that row taking on that value?  In places, I've got essentially the same setup as you, and am experiencing this strange issue.

Answer (score 9):

The only way to get the scroll bar is via a lookup, which is a bit of a hack, but it will work as long as you do it *after* the table has been rendered on the scene. You need

```
ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) table.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
```

Note that there's no need to mess with user events: you can just observe the scroll bar's `value` property directly:

```
verticalBar.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue.doubleValue() >= verticalBar.getMax()) {
        // add more data...
    }
});
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddMoreTableDataOnScrollToBottom extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));


        addMoreData(table, 20);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) table.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        verticalBar.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.doubleValue() >= verticalBar.getMax()) {
                addMoreData(table, 20);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addMoreData(TableView<Item> table, int numItems) {
        Task<List<Item>> dataRetrieveTask = new Task<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Item> call() throws Exception {
                // mimic connect to db:
                Thread.sleep(500);
                List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
                int nextItem = table.getItems().size() + 1 ;
                for (int i = nextItem; i < nextItem + numItems; i++ ){
                    items.add(new Item("Item "+i, i));
                }
                return items ;
            }
        };
        dataRetrieveTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> table.getItems().addAll(dataRetrieveTask.getValue()));
        new Thread(dataRetrieveTask).start();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> prop) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {

        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I get null even if the ScrollBar is present.

Comment: Modify ` table.lookup` to ` table.lookupAll`. Then it will work for all cases.

Comment: @AdamArold Ah, yes, there was a bug introduced at some point (since this was posted) that prevents lookups working with CSS pseudoclasses. I'll update when I am back at the computer.

Comment: I have had the same problem with scrollBars = null, so it looks to me that it's more like ```lookupAll(".scroll-bar")``` and the return is a set of all the ScrollBars which can be distinguished by their orientation.